# I am facing issues printing things on repl.it

Tags: python-3.x, console, replit

I am new to repl.it and I was trying to print the python version using this code [Print Version of the Python Running on the Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwVAw.png)

Here's the code:

```
import sys
print("Python version")
print (sys.version)
print("Version info.")
print (sys.version_info)
```

but it prints absolutely nothing. Trying to do the same thing onto Jupyter Notebook and my code works. While I know I can print the version directly from the shell tab out there but I was wondering what's wrong with my code and why it isn't working with repl.it

This seems to be the same for user input as well where I try to do

```
name = input("Print my name?\n")
```

but it prints absolutely nothing onto the console. I am sure someone here must know what am I missing here. Sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: Oh btw, printing functions ain't an issue. Just the things that need you to interact with the shell.

Comment: Works fine for me... Maybe share the link of the repl that's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "Help!  My REPL won't run"

Here are six reasons your Python REPL.it environment may not be working.

### Checklist to fix common problems

1. Have you configured your `Run ▶️`? [image: Run button on REPL.it]
   Repl.it doesn't automatically run your current working document. [Configuring your `Run ▶️` button](https://docs.replit.com/repls/dot-replit) will enable replit to know what to do when you hit the button.
   **Configuring the "Run" Button**
   A file named `.replit` can be added to any repl in order to customize the behavior of the "Run" button. Written in [toml](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml), a `.replit` file looks something like:

   ```
   run = "<run command here>"
   language = "<repl language>" # optional
   ```

   In the snippet above, `run` is a string which will be executed in the shell whenever you hit the "Run" button. The `language` helps the IDE understand how to provide features like [packaging](https://blog.repl.it/upm) and [code intelligence](https://blog.repl.it/intel). This is normally configured for you when you clone from a Git repository.
   The `.replit` file can also provide other configuration hints. The full specification is provided below:

   - `run`: Command that is executed when the run button is clicked
   - `language`: Reserved
   - `onBoot`: Command that is executed once when the repl first starts up
   - `packager.afterInstall`: Command that is executed after a new package is installed
   - `packager.ignoredPaths`: List of paths to ignore while attempting to guess packages ([More about installing packages](https://docs.repl.it/repls/packages/#DirectImports))
   - `packager.ignoredPackages`: List of modules to never attempt to guess a package for, when installing packages ([More about installing packages](https://docs.repl.it/repls/packages/#DirectImports))

   **Example .replit File**

   ```
   run="python main.py"
   language="python3"
   onBoot="echo Booting up!"

   [packager]
   afterInstall="date >> package_install_log"
   ignoredPaths=[".git"]
   ignoredPackages=["twitter", "discord"]
   ```
2. Attempt running the `*.py` script through the interactive shell instead of console. [image: Screen recording of running the Python script in shell] If the script runs in console, you may be needing to diagnose the shell. See choices below.
3. Check that the [Browser Developer Console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole) is not showing any errors [image: Screenshot of developer console] If you see errors, you may be having issues with your browser or extensions. Try [disabling browser extensions temporarily](https://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off).
4. REPL.it relies on Google Cloud Platform services for its backend functionality and sometimes those servers are unresponsive. Check the [REPL.it status page](https://status.replit.com) or [the REPLIT Twitter account](https://twitter.com/Replit) to see if they're having a GCP backend service outage. If they haven't updated recently, they may be responding to an unreported outage. Check [Google's own GCP status page here](https://status.cloud.google.com). You can also Tweet at [the CEO of Repl.it here](https://twitter.com/amasad).
5. Try *refreshing* the REPL.it environment locally. Clear the console output and scroll-back by using the ✖️ next to the search icon . [image: clear your console output] Also, try exiting the Python REPL with `exit()` to see if it will respond. [image: type exit() to terminate the active Python repl]
6. If #5 doesn't work, try an [empty-cache hard reload](https://fabricdigital.co.nz/blog/how-to-hard-refresh-your-browser-and-clear-cache).[image: screenshot of hard reload in Google Chrome browser] This can help to expunge unresponsive javascript, broken html, misbehaving css, and any unmetabolized toxins from the bowels of your browser.